# Realtime output from python script using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess

After searching around, I defined a function to execute command like in terminal:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
def execute_cmd(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):  # b'' here for python3
        sys.stdout.write(line.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))

    error = p.stderr.read().decode()
    if error:
        raise Exception(error)
```

It works fine(output is realtime), when i

```
execute_cmd('ping -c 5 www.google.com')
```

However, when i use `execute_cmd` to run a python script, the output will print out until the process is done.

```
execute_cmd('python test.py')
```

#### script: test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

print('hello')
time.sleep(2)
print('hello, again')
```

How can i fix it? thanks!

---

Sorry for not explaining why 'catch the stdout and then write it to stdout again'. Here i really want to do is catching script outputs to logger, the logger output them to screen(StreamHandler) and log file(FileHandler). I builded and tested the logger part, now the 'execute' part. And ignore the `stdout=` parameter seems not work.

#### pipeline:

1. setup logger;
2. redirect STDOUT, STDERR to logger;
3. execute scripts;

Because of step 2, if i ignore `stdout=` parameter, the outputs of scripts will still output to STDOUT, and will not log in file.

Maybe i can set `stdout=` to logger?

Comment: Why you catch the `stdout` and then write it to `stdout` again? You can just ignore that parameter.

Comment: @Sraw Sorry for not explaining that, I really want to do is catching script outputs to logger,  the logger output them to screen(StreamHandler) and log file(FileHandler). I builded and tested logger, now the 'execute' part. And ignore the `stdout=` parameter will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem of the underlying output system, notably on Linux or other Unix-like systems. The io library is smart enough to flush output on each `\n` when it detects that output is directed to a terminal. But this automatic flush does not occur when output is redirected to a file or a pipe, probably for performance reasons. It is not really a problem when only the data matters, but it leads to weird behaviour when timing matters too.

Unfortunately I know no simple way to fix it from the caller program(*). The only possibility is to have the callee force flushing on each line/block or to use unbuffered output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import sys

print('hello')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
print('hello, again')
```

---

(*) The bullet proof way would be to use a pseudo-terminal. The caller controls the master side and passes the client side to the callee. The library will detect a terminal and will automatically flushes on each line. But it is no longer portable outside the Unix world and is not really a *simple* way.

Comment: The reason behind problem is more important than solutions, thx for show me the rabbit hole.