# Run C program with interactive IO using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, io, processbuilder

I’m developing an IDE kind of software for C/C++ using `java` (although there are lots of available, but I want my own) that can compile and execute C or C++ program. So I tried a simple program to compile and execute the C program in java using `Process` and `ProcessBuilder.`

Here is my simple java program which compiles and execute C program:

```
public class RunProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "-o", "first", "first.c").start().waitFor(); //To Compile the source file using gcc and wait for compilation


/*
    Although I've to handle error-stream but 
for now, my assumption is that there is no error 
in program.
*/


        ProcessBuilder run = new ProcessBuilder("./first");

        execute.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process runProcess = run.start();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(runProcess.getInputStream());

        new Thread(sr).start(); //A new thread to handle output of program . 

    //rest of coding to provide input using OutputStream of 'runProcess' and to close the stream.

    }
}

class StreamReader implements Runnable {

    private InputStream reader;

   public StreamReader(InputStream inStream) {
      reader = inStream;

   }

   @Override
   public void run() {

      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int size = 0;
        try {

            while ((size = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {

                System.out.println(new String(buf));
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

And here is my `first.c` program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int k;

    printf("input a: ");

    scanf("%d", &a);
    for(k = 0; k < a; k++)
        printf("k = %d\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create interactive `IO` console just like most of the IDEs or command terminals(Terminal in Linux bases OS and command prompt in Windows based OS). For above example: **firstly, it should print `“Input a: “`and then wait for input to be provided and then rest of program.** But It won’t work as I thought, as **it doesn’t print the result of `printf` statement appeared before `scanf` until I provide input possibly using `OutputStream`.**

I googled for my problem and visited many links but didn't get solution. Mean while, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479152/why-does-reading-from-process-inputstream-block-altough-data-is-available) link which suggest to append `fflush` after every `printf` statement or use `setbuf` or `setvbuf` methods (from some other sub-links) to clear the buffer. But a new person (who is going to learn C) might not be aware of `fflush` or these functions and he/she will never use it, as it doesn’t require in other IDEs or not even on terminals.
**How can I solve this problem and can build integrated console for my IDE**

Here is a glimpse of what I want:

[image: animation of Interactive IO]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50386656/3545273) of mine gives a more in depth explaination of what happens under the hood and why it should be handled in callee program. The only alternative I can imagine would be pseudo-terminals in Unix-Linux but it is a rather advanced (and non portable) way.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I've a look upon your answer, but I didn't understand that how your answer would help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to solve it (except with pseudo-terminals)...

Comment: @SergeBallesta so does eclipse and other IDEs uses pseudo-terminals

Answer (score 2):

From the comments above, think adding a little bit of explanation of how buffering for I/O streams works makes sense here.

What happens behind the scenes when calling `printf(3)` and the like is that the data is written to a buffer until the buffer fills up or some trigger happens.
The content of the buffer is then copied from the buffer to the actual output device/another output buffer ...
The trigger is usually encountering a line end (`\n` under Linux/Unix).
Thus a crude version of this buffering is:

```
struct buffered_file_t {

    char* buffer;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t current_char;
    FILE* file;

};

void flush_buffered(struct buffered_file_t* file) {

    assert(0 != file);
    assert(0 != file->buffer);

    fwrite(file->buffer, file->current_char, 1, file->file);
    file->current_char = 0;

}


void print(struct buffered_file_t* file, const char* str) {

    assert(0 != file);
    assert(0 != file->buffer);
    assert(0 != str);

    for(size_t i = 0;  0 != str[i]; ++i) {

        if(file->current_char >= file->capacity - 1) flush_buffered(file);
        file->buffer[file->current_char++] = str[i];
        if('\n' == str[i]) flush_buffered(file);

    }

}
```

Now, if you invoke `print` like

```
const size_t BUFSIZE = 100;

struct buffered_file_t stdout_buffered = {
    .buffer = calloc(1, BUFSIZE),
    .capacity = BUFSIZE,
    .current_char = 0,
    .file= stdout,
};

print(&stdout_buffered, "Naglfar\n");
print(&stdout_buffered, "Surthur");
```

You won't see `Surthur` appear on`stdout` ever.
In order to have it written from the buffer to `stdout`, you have to either

- call `flush_buffered` explicitly
- Disable buffering by reducing the buffer size (`buffered_file.capacity = 1` in the example above)

In your case, you cannot invoke `fflush(3)` explicitly (that's what you stated as requirement). thus the only means left is disabling buffering.

How to do this is OS dependent, IMHO.
For Linux, look at `stdbuf(1)` from the Coreutils package to find out how to diable buffering for certain streams of foreign processes.

Answer (score 0):

Under GNU/Linux, for switching off buffering for the standard I/O streams, you could use [`stdbuf(1)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html)like so:

```
 ....
 ProcessBuilder run = new ProcessBuilder("stdbuf", "-o0", "./first");
 ....
```

Add `-e0` and `-i0` options if you want to turn off buffering for `stderr` and `stdin` as well.

Of course, it would be nicer if you would not have to rely upon external tools but could do switching off buffering in your own code - simplest thing is to have a look at the source of `stdbuf`, but I guess it would end up in you having to use the JNI, and then, I guess, I would just stick to `stdbuf` ...

Comment: I've tried your code and it produces exeception: can't run program 'stdbuf' as studbuf is not an executable program

Comment: Of course, `stdbuf` must be in path - install `coreutils`. My intention was to give you a starter were to look, if you plan to stick to precisely `stdbuf` for solving your problem, I recommend distributing it along with your software.

Comment: Bear  Actually I don't want to stick with `stdbuf` rather I want a solution, so I'm trying everything. As I've searched a lot on internet, I didn't find any first step solution

Comment: From Your point, I've to distribute it along with my IDE which is little cumbersome. And I think, setting buffer to 0 is not a good practice as program uses buffer for fastening the execution and for some other purpose.

Comment: Hi again, so, there are two points I want to reply to: As I said, I intended to give you `stdbuf` as a hint were to start looking. You know C, thus look at its source code.

Comment: Second point: You realize that having `stdout` of your `./first` buffered is the root cause of your problem? Then either you disable buffering `stdout` live on with your problem, as far as I can see. Unfortunately, you can't have the cake and eat it, too. Moreover, `stdout` and the likes are mainly buffered in order to provide e.g. line-by-line manipulations. Switching off buffering for `stdout` in your case won't inflict heavy performance penalties. Just compare https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html , which is buffered for the same ends.