# Get exe console lines from python

Tags: python

So I have an exe process, but I want to be able to copy the text written to the console (shell window) into python.

I want to be able to constantly retrieve the last 3 lines from the process, and handle them in Python.

Example (ish):

```
process = #start the process#
preLines = []
While True:
    if process.hasExited:
        break;
    lines = #Get the last 3 lines from process#
    if lines != preLines:
        Update(lines)
        preLines = lines
```

The reason for this is that I have a process I want to run, but the output to be sent elsewhere, not just the default console.
I have looked around, but I can't seem to find anything that works for me.

I am willing to have better suggestions as well, but would prefer something like this, as I do not want to edit the exe itself.

Comment: I think you should have a look to that other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50386143/3545273. As you are speaking of *exe process*, I assume that the underlying OS is Windows and you should not suffer the same problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta While informative, that doesn't solve the problem. The main problem is that when using popen, it pauses the thread until that process has completed. So using "start process.exe" in popen pauses the thread. Multithreading and async don't work because they do not set the variable 'process' until after the process closes. Also for some reason, I only every get a response of `(b'',None)` when using either process.communicate() or process.stdout.read().

Comment: Please show your attempt using `process.stdout.read`